# como adicionar UUID no esquema para prisma

Tags: mysql, prisma

como adicionar um ID ao invés de um id inteiro no prisma com mysql nesse modelo e essas relações de curtidas, posts, comentários, estão me incomodando para integrar

```
    generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "mysql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model user {
  id       Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  name     String?
  email    String    @unique
  password String    @db.VarChar(255)
  Post     Post[]
  Likes    Likes[]
  Comment  Comment[]
  About    About[]

  @@map("users")
}

model Post {
  id      Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  title   String?
  content String    @db.VarChar(255)
  userId  Int
  author  user      @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  Likes   Likes[]
  Comment Comment[]

  @@map("posts")
}

model Likes {
  id       Int  @id @default(autoincrement())
  userId   Int
  postId   Int
  curtidas Int
  user     user @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  post     Post @relation(fields: [postId], references: [id])

  @@map("likes")
}

model Comment {
  id      Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
  content String
  userId  Int
  postId  Int
  user    user   @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  post    Post   @relation(fields: [postId], references: [id])

  @@map("comments")
}

model About {
  id     Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
  userId Int
  city   String
  hobby  String
  state  String
  user   user   @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])

  @@map("abouts")
}
```

Comment: A [documentação](https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/storing-uuid-values-in-mysql-tables/) sugere alguns modos para adicionar um UUID.

Comment: eu consegui já, fui na doc e mudei para string ao inves de int, ficou assim id       String    @id @default(uuid())

Comment: Você está ciente que usar UUID como chave primária apresenta algumas disadvantage: Impacta no tamanho do banco de dados pois devido ao tamanho do UUID cada registro será aumentado em 16 bytes vezes o número de chaves primaria/estrangeiras no registro. Inutilização de índices baseados em chaves primaria/estrangeiras, UUID não é classificável e portanto não indexável. Diminui a performance de todas as instruções DML baseadas em chaves primaria/estrangeiras.

Comment: Perda de performance em consultas indexadas em colunas não UUID, no MySQL os índices são B+Tree cuja as folhas são a chave primária, como o UUID não é classificável a taxa de preenchimento das páginas do índice será muito baixa assim desperdiçando memória tanto em RAM quando disco, impactando também na performance.

Comment: qual o "certo" a fazer entao?

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score -1):

Uma maneira de resolver o problema é mudando do tipo da coluna id para o tipo String e no parâmetro default você chamar a função UUID(). A solução aqui foi inspirada na [documentação do mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/storing-uuid-values-in-mysql-tables/).

Ao adicionar a opção `@db.VarChar(36)` vai manter o tamanho da coluna de acordo com a nossa necessidade. Criando uma coluna com 36 caracteres.

Segue a mudança necessária na definição do seu *schema*:

```
id    String  @db.VarChar(36)  @id @default(uuid())
```

Segue um exemplo completo:

***schema.prisma***

```
// This is your Prisma schema file,
// learn more about it in the docs: https://pris.ly/d/prisma-schema

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "mysql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model User {
  id    String @db.VarChar(36) @id @default(uuid())
  email String  @unique
  name  String?
}
```

Você deve também modificar a maneira como devem ser relacionadas as chaves estrangeiras.
Para isso modifique os tipos da variável que será a referência ao id da tabela `user` na tabela `post`.

```
model Post {
  id      Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  title   String?
  content String  @db.VarChar(255)
  userId  String  @db.VarChar(36)
  author  user    @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])

  @@map("posts")
}
```

Depois adicione um atributo para fazer a relação entre os tipos `User` e `Post`. O resultado final será o seguinte:

```
model user {
  id       String  @id @default(uuid()) @db.VarChar(36)
  name     String?
  email    String  @unique
  password String  @db.VarChar(255)
  Post     Post[]

  @@map("users")
}
```

O resultado final é o seguinte:

```
// This is your Prisma schema file,
// learn more about it in the docs: https://pris.ly/d/prisma-schema

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "mysql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model user {
  id       String  @id @default(uuid()) @db.VarChar(36)
  name     String?
  email    String  @unique
  password String  @db.VarChar(255)
  Post     Post[]

  @@map("users")
}

model Post {
  id      Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  title   String?
  content String  @db.VarChar(255)
  userId  String  @db.VarChar(36)
  author  user    @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])

  @@map("posts")
}
```

Para aprender mais sobre tabelas e relações entre tabelas consulte a [documentação](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/relations)

Em caso de dúvidas, consulte a [documentação](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-schema-reference#string)